# How to convert from C# ref type to CLI\C++ ^% type

Tags: c++-cli

I am writing an application in Managed C++ (CLI\C++). In which I am using a library (.dll file) which is written in C#.

In a file I am encountering a problem.

I am implementing functions of an interface which is written in the library.

The declaration of a function in the library is as given below:

```
COMWORKSPACELib.IWorkspaceEvents.WorkspaceMessage(int, string, COMWORKSPACELib.EnumNotificationCode, COMWORKSPACELib.EnumNotificationType, string, ref COMWORKSPACELib.EnumNotificationReply);
```

When I write the same code in CLI\C++ the declaration is like:

```
WorkspaceMessage(int workspaceToken, String ^description, EnumNotificationCode ^code, EnumNotificationType ^type, String ^source, EnumNotificationReply ^%action);
```

Here, the compiler is giving me error that the “class must provide an implementation for the interface method”. Because the parameters passed in both function declarations are syntactically different.

Is there any alternative way to match the library declaration?

If I remove the “^’ & ‘%’ to match the library declaration then it gives further errors in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Are EnumNotifcationCode, EnumNotificationType, and EnumNotficationReply all enums?  That is, are they value types?  If so, then it should be declared as follows:

```
WorkspaceMessage(int workspaceToken, 
                 String^ description, 
                 EnumNotificationCode code, 
                 EnumNotificationType type, 
                 String^ source, 
                 EnumNotificationReply% action);
```

Comment: Then we need more info: What types are the three Enum* types I asked you about?  What is the return type?  The more info you provide the better chance of getting a good answer.